# How to inject mocked function within function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to modify how a function behaves within another function via mock on one of my tests. I'm able to correctly mock one function, but when that same function is used by another function, it behaves as if it was never mocked.

This is my code under test:

```js
export const returnNum = (num) => {
  return giveMe2();
};

export const giveMe2 = () => {
  return 2;
};
```

And my test:

```js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

const moduleUnderTest = require("../moduleUnderTest");

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('testing', () => {

  it('testing', () => {
    sinon.stub(moduleUnderTest, 'giveMe2').returns(5);
    console.log(moduleUnderTest.giveMe2()); // logs 5 to the console
    console.log(moduleUnderTest.returnNum(5)); // logs 2 to the console
  });
});
```

I would expect that the second call to log would log `5`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The mock replaces just module export, so unless you import that inner function, it cannot be mocked.